# Where from I can get some problems on Lagrange Theorem with solutions?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I want to solve some problems on Lagrange Theorem to practice with some solutions?
Please suggest me some link or some book.

Lagrange's theorem, in the mathematics of group theory, states that for any finite group $G$, the order (number of elements) of every subgroup $H$ of $G$ divides the order of $G$. The theorem is named after Joseph-Louis Lagrange. So if the order of a group is $m$ and order of a subgroup is $n$, $n|m$.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you clarify what theorem you are referring to? Based on the tag, I believe you mean the Mean Value Theorem, but Dietrich Burde's answer is about Lagrange Theorem in group theory.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem, in the mathematics of group theory, states that for any finite group G, the order (number of elements) of every subgroup H of G divides the order of G. The theorem is named after Joseph-Louis Lagrange.

Comment: Ok, that's more clear. In fact I just realised you had put the correct tags in the first place, but they have been changed by someone else, so the confusion wasn't your fault.

Answer (score 1):

There are exercises on Lagrange's Theorem in the lecture notes of J.S. Milne, with solutions, see [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html). For example, Exercise $1-4$, or Remark $4.2.2$, which is in fact an exercise with given solution.  See also the Additional Exercises in the Appendix, with Solutions.